# How to frame a json request from plsql?

Tags: sql, json, oracle, rest, plsql

I have a column in one of my table which stores the JSON tags seperated by ~
LDD~LCL~LCP~CId~Id~K~NC~EId~BId~WId~WSId~SSId

Now i have another column which have some default values and some dynamic values
false~true~false~~12345~0~false~0~2222~3333~999~55

How to frame a json request like this dynamically in PLSQL
{
  "LDD": false,
  "LCL": true,
  "LCP": false,
  "CId": {
    "Id": "12345",
    "K": 0
  },
  "NC": false,
  "EId": 0,
  "BId": "2222",
  "WId": "3333",
  "WSId": "999",
  "SSId": "55"
}
It shouldnt be hardcoded.Please help??

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: How can a dynamic process tell from your data that `Id` and `K` should be child nodes of `Cld`?

Comment: Request will be the same ,Im finding it difficult to frame a double nested request.The tags and data can be changed accordingly in the table.I need to pick the tags and values from the tables respectively and frame the json request